# create a google maps marker with javascript

Tags: google-maps

the browser says that google.maps is not defined

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: center,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
          });
          marker.setMap(map);
         </script>
        <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBxawz_fpkdpvsMZm_PozrDBznq7ph7bk0&callback=initMap"
           ></script>
       </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Show the rest of the relevant script...

Answer (score 0):

*you dont have to write as you have already mentioned map:map in the marker*

```
marker.setMap(map);
```

*the error google.map is not defined comes when javascript does not have its resources make sure your google key is initialised before writing this code*

Answer (score 0):

Put **all** the code that depends on the (asynchronously loaded) Google Maps Javascript API v3 **inside** the `initMap` (callback) function.

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script>
  window.initMap = function() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.0059413);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: center,
      zoom: 8
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: center,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```